# Can I refactor my xcode swift app into a lib?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an Xcode swift app that uses "import CoreBluetooth" to access a wearable.

Now, my teammate wants to use my functionality, and thus wants a lib (.a) that he can incorporate into his xcode GUI app.

Can I refactor my app into a lib for him to add to his GUI app?

Or, is the only way to create a new xcode lib project?

Comment: You should look into [Swift Package Manger](https://www.swift.org/package-manager/)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is yes, you can use the same project. You need to separate 2 things:

- Project is a design-time / code organization entity. One project can contain framework, app, tests, etc - all at the same time
- What actually dictates what is going to be built are *Targets*. Some targets will build an app, some will build the library etc. Each target may contain any subset of files from your project (as long as they compile).

So that's one way to go about it: create a second target for Framework, add relevant files to Build Phases > Compile Sources and voila.

The advantage is simplicity. The disadvantages are many: how do you know you didn't break compatibility with wearable? how do you know which file belongs to app, and which belongs to app and framework (sure, you can see when you click on file, or folder structure can help, but it's not going to stop the mistake from happening)? or what if compatibility your iOS app needs is different with what wearable app needs? how do you maintain versions of such framework? etc etc

So a much better cleaner way is to create a separate repo for your framework, and maintain it as an internal product you are sharing between various components. That way you can maintain clear versioning, compatibility, and address bugs without the fear of breaking either app or wearable. And you can include that framework in both projects using (like suggested above) Swift Package Manager, or CocoaPods, or even manually.